# Subset of the Cantor set is perfect

Tags: real-analysis

Is every closed non-empty subset of the Cantor set perfect?
Since the Cantor set itself has all the accumulation points within the set, I don't see why taking points away from the set would result in a non-perfect set, but I don't know how to prove this rigorously, or I might be totally wrong.

Comment: There are finite subsets.

Comment: As well as single point subsets.

Comment: "Since the Cantor set itself has all the accumulation points within the set" -- but that's true of any closed set. The important thing here is  a perfect set has no isolated points.

Comment: For an infinite counterexample consider $\{0\}\cup\{3^{-n}:n\in\Bbb N\}$.

Comment: I don't want to get fuzzy but if you think about it, a subset can be any collection of points.  What the superset is can't actually force any restrictions on what a subset must be.  A superset can force what a subset *can't* be but it can't force what a subset must be.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a single point $x$ . . .

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{0\} \cup \{ 1/3^n : n=1,2,3,\ldots \}$ is a closed subset of the Cantor set, but it has lots of isolated points.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect sets (in Polish spaces) have cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. This means that countable (and finite) closed sets cannot be perfect.